# Gmail - LOGIN Invalid credentials error no two factor authentication

Tags: python, gmail, imap, imaplib

I´m trying to connect my python-scrip with Gmail.
No two factor authentication... (i checked manually)

```
SMTP_SERVER = "imap.gmail.com" 
mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(SMTP_SERVER) 
mail.login(emailAddress,password)
```

And after `login`  i got this error:

> [AUTHENTICATIONFAILED] Invalid credentials (Failure)

I also try to add port `993`: `mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(SMTP_SERVER, '993')`

UPDATE

I also try port `465` and got this `exception`:

> Exception occurred: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed
>   because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of
>   time, or established connection failed because connected host has
>   failed to respond

Comment: have you tried `port = 465 # for SSL`. Another thing about gmail is that you need to allow 3rd party apps to access it https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255

Comment: Yes i have try, please see my update

Comment: Have you allowed 3rd party apps access your email account as per the instructions? Also, do you care about using imaplib vs smtplib?

Comment: I dont think gmail allows login and password anymore you need to use xoauth2

Comment: user @Biarys, thanks a lot, i changed 3rd party to On and this woks fine

Answer (score 0):

```
import imaplib

M = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL("imap.gmail.com",993)
M.login('YourEmail', 'Your Plain text password')
M.starttls() #Run it once and once you get error then remove it and recompile and you will be connected
M.select()
typ, data = M.search(None, 'ALL')
for num in data[0].split():
    typ, data = M.fetch(num, '(RFC822)')
    print('Message %s\n%s\n' % (num, data[0][1]))
M.close()
M.logout()
```

[image: Output attached here]